# Relation between the number of goals remaining and using the wrong operator in a General Problem Solver

Tags: problem-solving

In Peter Norvig's [Paradigms of Artificial Intelligence Programming](http://www.amazon.in/Paradigms-Artificial-Intelligence-Programming-Studies/dp/1558601910), chapter 4, which is about the all-famous General Problem Solver (GPS). In this chapter, the author asks a question (4.4), which is as follows:

> **The Not Looking after You don't Leap Problem**
>
> Write a program that keeps track of the remaining goals so that it doesn't get stuck considering only one possible operation when others will eventually lead to the goal.
>
> **HINT:** have `achieve` take an extra argument indicating the goals that remain to be achieved after the current goal is achieved. `achieve` should succeed only if it can achieve the current goal and also `achieve-all` the remaining goals."

Here's the description of these functions

1. `achieve`: We input a goal, the list of operators, and the current state, in the `achieve` function, which checks if the goal is in the `state` already, if not, then checks if the goal is recursive, if not, then finds all the `appropriate` operators and then applies them, until the goal os achieved. Or `achieve` returns a nil.
2. `achieve-all`: This has a list of goals as an input, which it tries to achieve using the `achieve` function. Moreover, it makes sure that all the goals are in the final state. Otherwise, it returns a nil.

The problem that I face is to find a relation between "getting stucked" over an operator and maintaining the number of goals remaining. Moreover, the version of `achieve` in the GPS program checks for all the operators that can achieve the goal, and then apply only the one that does the work.

Let's forget this for a while, and consider the hint. It says that we should have an extra argument maintaining the goals that are remaining. But how will it help a goal, which is stuck because of applying the wrong operator?

There seems to be no relation between them. I know I'm missing something here, but I can't find that.